# Java: Nested If Statements

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm making a video game for a project and it's a text-based RPG where there are a lot of decisions that can be made (branching story). To start off my game, the user inputs "1" and within the if statement, there is another if statement. But whenever I run the code, I'd input "1", the println text would show and the build would just end instead of continuing on. Can I not have nested if-statements like this?

```
    System.out.println("--------------------------");
    System.out.println("# What Might've Happened #");
    System.out.println("--------------------------\n");
    System.out.println("You wake up. It's almost 7. Better get moving,\ncan't be late on the first day of school!");
    System.out.println("1. Continue");
    System.out.println("\nPress 1 and then press enter");

    String input = in.nextLine();
```

This code displays, but it doesn't continue after here.

```
    if(input.equals("1")) {
            System.out.println("\nYou get to school at 7:15.\nYou can either:");
            System.out.println("1. Go to your first class.");
            System.out.println("2. Go see if you can make some friends.");
```

---

the rest of the code

```
    switch (input) {
        case "1":
            System.out.println("");
            break;
        case "2":
            System.out.println("\n Do you want to go to the media center or the locker bay?");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println ("Invalid Command!");
            break;
        }
    }
else {
    System.out.println ("Invalid Command!");
}
```

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: So, after pressing `1`, you print some text, then jump straight to a `switch` statement, where a value of `1`, which `input` still is equal to, prints a empty line and you code then exists the `main` method, terminating the program...did you forget wait for some more input from the user first?

Comment: There are no nested if-statements here. What is your question? NB Netbeans has nothing to do with it either way.

Comment: Have a while loop with an exit condition

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not actually asking the user for more input...

```
String input = in.nextLine();

if(input.equals("1")) {
    //... input is still equal to "1"
    switch (input) {
        case "1":
            System.out.println("");
            break;
```

So, basically, your code hits the `if` statement, dumps some text to the user, executes the `switch` statement, where `input` is still equal to `1`, prints a blank line and then exits the `main` method and terminates the VM...because there's no loop to stop it ... I assume that will come later

Basically, you need to request some more input from the user...

```
String input = in.nextLine();

if(input.equals("1")) {
    //... input is still equal to "1"
    input = in.nextLine();
    switch (input) {
        case "1":
            System.out.println("");
            break;
```

Comment: Okay that makes sense. One last question. To ask for more input, would I have to make another string?String input2 = in.nextLine();

Comment: Not unless you needed it for some reason, for example, you were relying on the value of `input` after the `if` statement completed for example

Comment: Okay, I got it. Thank you so much!